# Не работает метод ga.getAll() в последней версии React

Tags: ruby, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, google-analytics, phantomjs

В последней версии ReactJS не могу выполнить код в консоли JS `ga.getAll();`.
Выполняю код внутри PhantomJS.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
driver.get 'https://www.vezetvsem.ru/booking'
driver.execute_script 'return ga.getAll();'
```

Вместо объекта возвращается ошибка:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'ga.getAll()')
```

Тот же самый код прекрасно работает в Chrome или в более старой версии ReactJS.

Есть какие-нить идеи, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Возможно, страница на тот момент ещё формируется, и надо подождать появления какого-то характерного элемента?

Comment: Скорее всего — это не так. Дело в том, что пока страница полностью не прогрузится, код не перейдёт на строку `driver.execute_script`. Более того, просто вернув версию ReactJS на более старшую — всё работает.